# Bucket already existing when creating stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, serverless

```
  TokboxArchiveBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Description: "S3 Bucket to store TokBox archive videos"
    Properties:
      BucketName: !Sub "zelhus-archive"
      NotificationConfiguration:
        LambdaConfigurations:
          - Event: "s3:ObjectCreated:*"
            Filter:
              S3Key:
                Rules:
                  - Name: "prefix"
                    Value: !Sub ${TokBoxKey}
            Function: !GetAtt LambdaFunctionArchiveTokboxSession.Arn
```

I was creating stack but got error using above config in serverless.yaml

> Error - zelhus-archive already exists

Yes, before I have bucket already exists because I have created it. If I don't create then I get below error.

> Error - Unable to validate the following destination configurations
> (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidArgument;
> Request ID: ***********; S3 Extended Request ID: *****; Proxy: null)

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure what you are asking, but s3 bucket names are globally unique, meaning that you cannot have two buckets with the same name, across all of aws.

In order to deploy your stack with an s3 bucket, you need to either change the bucket name in the .yml file or delete the bucket manually before deploying.